# How to create RestTemplate service for multiple base URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, polymorphism

I want to implement `RestTemplate` service in Spring Boot that can work for multiple base URLs.
Here is my service class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private String baseUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    public ResponseEntity<String> method1() {...}

    public ResponseEntity<String> method2() {...}

}
```

I am thinking how to inject that `baseUrl` when calling my service methods. Maybe I can create `MyService` constructor and `get` method to create new `MyService` instance:

```
    public MyService(String baseUrl) {
       this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public static MyService get(String baseUrl) {
        return new MyService(baseUrl);
    }
```

But using this approach I will not be able to get `RestTemplate` autowired correctly.
So I am wondering what would be the best approach to solve my problem and not to create other classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could skip setting `baseUrl` for `RestTemplate` and instead provide full url when doing requests:

```java
var restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.exchange("https://google.pl", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

Url's can be provided when constructing object, by creating a `@Configuration` class containing `MyService` definition:

```java
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    // Creating rest template
}

@Bean
public MyService restTemplate() {
    // var baseUrls = ...
    // return new MyService(baseUrls, restTemplate())
}
```

My recommendation would be to change approach, assuming each `baseUrl` is a completely different external service, it would be best to inject multiple `RestTemplate`, each containing it's own `baseUrl`.

Additionally if possible, consider moving away from RestTemplate in favour of `WebClient` or `OpenFeign`, as `RestTemplate` is in maintenance mode:

```
<p><strong>NOTE:</strong> As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with
only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please,
consider using the {@code org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient}
which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.
```

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java